# CSS - Selector to target element with the greatest order?

Tags: javascript, html, css

*First off, I know that this can be done via JS (and currently have this approach implemented), but I'd prefer to use native CSS if possible. Less JS, less DOM access, and so forth.*

**TL;DR**

Is there a CSS selector to target elements with a specific CSS property? More specifically, to target the element with the *greatest* `order` property?

Something like...

```
el:greatest(property:order) {...}
```

**Setup**

I've got a list, something like...

```
<div class="list-container">
    <ul class="list">
        <li style="order: 0;">One</li>
        <li style="order: 1;">two</li>
        <li style="order: 2;">three</li>
        ...
        <li style="order: n;">Last</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This is used as an infinite scroller, and so the entire list (`ul`) scrolls within the container. The details aren't hugely important, but essentially the number of list items is constant, and are recycled as the user scrolls.

*Clarification: Even though the number of list items is constant, there is no bounds to the maximum order number. If the initial orders are `order=0, 1, 2, 3` (list of four items), then `0->4`, `1->5`, `2->6`, and so on. Only one order is changed at a time - either to greater than all others (end of the list) or lesser than all others (start of the list).*

I accomplish this recycling by displaying the list as a `flex-box` and changing the order of the list items programattically.

More pertinent CSS is something like...

```
.list-container {
    overflow: scroll;
}

ul.list {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;

    list-style: none;
}

li {
    ... other rules
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
li:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Each list item has a `bottom-margin`, which acts as a buffer between each item (purely for aesthetics). BUT! It looks dumb when you scroll to the bottom of the list and there is an unnecessary margin before the bottom of the list container. Therefor, set the `last-child` to not have a bottom margin.

The list ends up looking something like...

[image: Initial List]

... *note: list BG set to `red` so you can see the padding, and `li:last-child` has BG set to `aqua`, so you can see which item is being treated as the last*

Problem solved, right!?

**So, The Problem...**

(Assume the list has `n` list items.)

In a normal list, the above CSS would work great. The issue comes when I take the top list item (`order: 0;`) and reassign the order so that it is moved to the bottom of the list (`order: n+1;`). Even though the list item might be *painted* and *displayed* at the bottom of the list, it is still treated within the DOM as the ***first*** list item.

The DOM looks like...

```
<div class="list-container">
    <ul class="list">
        <li style="order: n+1;">One</li>
        <li style="order: 1;">two</li>
        <li style="order: 2;">three</li>
        ...
        <li style="order: n;">Last</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And the result looks like...

[image: Issue List]

Because list item `order: n;` is still the `last-child` within the DOM, its bottom margin is removed, even though there is another list item displayed below it.

The same issue arrises when using `margin-top` and `li:first-child`. It's inescapable!

**So, Can I...?**

Is there a native CSS way to target the element with the greatest order number? Or perhaps there is another CSS-only trick to accomplish the same?

Much thanks!

Comment: You could use Javascript to sort them by order and select the last one in the array.

Comment: @Barmar that probably wouldn't work. The infinite list is based off of [this project](https://www.thecssninja.com/javascript/scrolllistview). The scrolling happens very quickly, and having to go through every list item and reassign their order would be too costly to provide a smooth experience. There's a video in the link I provided, showing how the DOM updates, and how fast it all needs to happen.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of removing the margin on the last `li` element, you could hide it by setting the bottom margin of the `ul` element to -5px and setting the overflow property to hidden.

Comment: This only works if I set a definite height to `ul` (because flex box?), and then use `overflow: hidden`. Knowing what height to make the `ul` is easier said than done, since in my case the list items can be variable height. All said, I might try to pursue this particular solution, if nothing else comes up. Most applicable yet.

Comment: Just tested. As-is, this solution doesn't work. The `ul` height (without being set) does show that it's being shortened by the negative margin, but the overflow is still visible. It can be fixed, however! The `ul` needs to have a parent with `overflow: hidden`. The parent will adjust to the *perceived* height of the `ul` (which including the negative margin).

Answer (score 0):

Could you set a margin on the [`::after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) pseudo element on your `<ul>`?

E.g.

```
ul.list::after {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand how this would help. Wouldn't this just add additional margin to the entire list itself, but not the individual items?

Comment: Yeah, I just tested it. I think you misunderstand what I'm asking for. All your solution did was add a margin to the top of the list (`ul`).

Answer (score 0):

Since `the number of list items is constant` is said in the question, you can just set the CSS for the largest order element, using the attribute selector.

**DISCLAIMER:**

> But please note, this selector is very **`fragile`** and the selector
> contents needs to be exactly the same as the contents of the style
> attribute.

```css
li[style*="order: 4;"] {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.list-container {
  overflow: auto;
}

ul.list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  ... other rules margin-bottom: 5px;
}

li:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="list-container">
  <ul class="list">
    <li style="order: 4;">One</li>
    <li style="order: 1;">two</li>
    <li style="order: 2;">three</li>
    <li style="order: 3;">Last</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I should have clarified. The number of elements is constant, but the order numbers are not. If I have a list of *four* items (`order=0..3`), then I would change 0->4. The new list orders would be `order=1..4`. And then 2->5, 3->6, and so on. Only one list item changes at a time, and there is no bound to the order number. I'll edit my original question.

Comment: @Birrel I am not sure there is a CSS selector for that! you can just keep the increment constant I guess, then this will work!

Comment: Your solution would definitely work if my situation were a little different. The number of list elements (`li`) is constant, but more and more data is pulled (via AJAX and pagination) as the user scrolls. I could write a script to just return random data, and there would be no end to how far the user could scroll (literally infinite, until the browser crashed)

Comment: If something is moving them cant you just use what ever moves them to add the correct class name where it needs to be?

Comment: @Marie that's what I'm doing, but it still means I have to *programatically* remove the `.list-end` class from the current end item, and add it to the new end item. Surely this can't be nearly as quick and efficient as having a CSS rule automatically handle it all.